# Align text in a drop-down form Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an inline form in a row that contains an email form and a drop down form. After resizing, the text on the drop down has lost its original positioning (text on the left, arrow on the right.) I tried using:

```
text-align: left;
```

However, my arrow is not aligned to the right, and I have no idea how to do so.

[image: Text is aligned left correctly, but arrow is not aligned right.]

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email-form">
      </div> 
       </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"> Interested In... </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
body
{
  background: #000639;
}

#email-form 
{
    line-height: 250%;
    margin-right: 115px;
    width: 158%;
}

#dropdown
{
    line-height: 250%;
    width: 238%;
    text-align: left;
}

.row
{
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Full screen:

[image]

Comment: Can you try removing the style `width: 238%` applied to `#dropdown`? It's extending its parent's width. Is there a reason to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the arrow by using the `::after` selector.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: -155px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000639;
}

#email-form {
  line-height: 250%;
  margin-right: 115px;
  width: 158%;
}

#dropdown {
  line-height: 250%;
  width: 238%;
  text-align: left;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: -155px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email-form">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"> Interested In... </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the left-margin to the ::after selector.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuk92w54/)

```
.dropdown-toggle::after{

margin-left: 3.3em;
}
```

Comment: resizing the window distorts spacing

Answer (score 0):

This effect can easily be obtained by using Flexbox. Add `display:flex;` to your `#dropdown` definition and set `align-items: center;` so that the elements will be centered vertically within its container.

To make sure your first element sticks to the left, and the right dropdown arrow sticks to the right. You can set `justify-content: space-between`, this will try and fill up all the space between the two items.

```
#dropdown {
  line-height: 250%;
  width: 238%;
  text-align: left;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Long live flexbox!